# Prove using this definition that for two independent random variables $X,Y$ we have that $P_{X+Y}=P_X*P_Y$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $ \mu $ and $ \nu $ be measures on $ (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) $. The convolution of $ \mu $ and $ \nu $ is denoted $ \mu * \nu $ and is  defined as
$$
(\mu * \nu)(B) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathbb{1}_B(x+y) (\mu \otimes \nu)(dx,dy)
$$
for every $ B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) $.

---

I want to prove using this definition that for two *independent* random variables $X,Y$ we have that
$P_{X+Y}=P_X*P_Y$. Suppose that $ s(x,y) = x + y $. Then using the image measure and independece ($P_X \otimes P_Y = P_{(X,Y)}$), I can make the following computation:
$$ P_X*P_Y(B) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathbb{1}_B(s(x,y)) (P_X \otimes P_Y)(dx,dy) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathbb{1}_B(x,y) (P_{(X,Y)}\circ s^{-1})(dx,dy)   $$
However now I am a bit stuck, how can I continue from here or am I even on the right track? I want to end up with $ P_{X+Y}(B) $ at the end... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Measures. No it not an exercise, rather it is for at project I am writing of infinite divisibility. I would like to derive from a general definition of convolution of measures, the known property that the convolution is just the distribution of the sum of two independent random variables.

Comment: In the first paragraph, you write "for every $B\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R^2)$, but that's not correct (and it doesn't match its usage in the integrand); $B$ should be in $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, I will correct it

Comment: $P_{(X,Y)}\circ s^{-1}$ is a measure on $\mathbb R$. So, your last integral does not make sense.